# css3 transition changing padding shrinks element by 1 px during animation

Tags: html, css

I have input field with large padding. When it is focused or contains value padding is changed and this change is animated with css3 `transition: all 0.5s;` problem is that in chrome for transition duration element height changes from 42px to 41.998px and chrome renders that as 41px causing content to jump up by 1px during animation.

```css
input {
  padding: 10px;
  transition:all 0.5s;
}

input:focus {
  padding: 20px 10px 0;  
  outline:none;
}
```

```html
<input type="text">
```

Comment: No problem seen on a older version of Chrome (v43).

Answer (score 0):

What's happening here is that you're actually animating 2 properties; `padding-top` is transitioning from 10px to 20px and `padding-bottom` is transitioning from 10px to 0px. Depending on various factors, your browser may struggle to animate both properties at *exactly* the same time - especially when the `transition-property` is set to `all` - leading to some "flickering" in the element's height as, currently, its height is calculated by adding together the `line-height`, `padding` and `border`.

One way to get around this would be to give the element a specific `height` so that that value does not have to be calculated at each stage during the transition.

```css
input{
  border:1px solid #999;
  box-sizing:border-box;
  height:42px;
  line-height:20px;
  outline:0;
  padding:10px;
  transition:padding .5s;
}
input:focus{
  padding:20px 10px 0;
}
```

```html
<input>
```